# django-widget-tweaks: removing "required" for check-box-input

Tags: django-widget-tweaks

Getting "Please check this box if you want to proceed" error when I want to submit False value for the checkbox.  I am using django-widget-tweaks, forms-Form for form.
Model has is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
Form has is_active=forms.BooleanField(required=False)
Html

```
<div class="form-check">
            {{ form.is_active.label_tag }}
            {% render_field form.is_active class='form-control form-check-input'  %} 
        </div>
```

This is based on Firefox browser.
In forms, added required=False in both forms.CharField(required=False) and forms.BooleanField(required=False).
From the Firefox inspector: CharField, the "required" is not added and can be submitted without adding a text, but for BooleanField, the required is added as required='False'. This still cause an error and not allow to enter without adding a check.
If the required='False' is manually removed via Firefox Inspector, it allows to enter without check.
Why doesn't required='False' not work in Firebox?
Why does adding required='False' for BooleanField (check-box-input) instead of removing "required" like in CharField?
How can we just remove "required" from BooleanField when using check-box-input?

Advanced thanks!

Comment: solved problem?